Can't connect to firebase auth emulator
Operating System
Windows 11
Environment
Chrome Version 127.0.6533.122 (Official Build) (64-bit), nodejs v20.14.0
Firebase SDK Version
^10.13.0
Firebase SDK Product(s)
Auth
Project Tooling
react-native with expo go
Detailed Problem Description

create a user on emulators
get this Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).
it works with firebase cloud

Steps and code to reproduce issue
run these commands

npx create-expo-app@latest ./ --template blank
md firebase
cd firebase
firebase login
firebase init
firebase emulators:start
npx expo install firebase
npx expo start

create this file in ./firebase/firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { connectAuthEmulator, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***",
    measurementId: "***",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth();
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://127.0.0.1:9099");

change App.js like this
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { auth } from "./firebase/firebase";
export default function App() {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "test@gmail.com", "test1234")
        .then((userCredential) => {
            console.log(userCredential);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.code, err.message);
        });
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    );
}

open the app on expo go on iOS
